# libMAPSJNI.so crashed when displaying the map for the first time on a specific device

Tags: android, crash, here-api

I meet  libMAPSJNI.so crashed when displaying the map for the first time on a specific device

OS：Android 8.0
Chipset：Qualcomm Snapdragon 450
CPU：Octa-Core ARM Cortex-A53
GPU：Adreno 506

> 12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505): *****       
>          ***** 12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505): Build fingerprint:
>   'samsung/j8y18ltedd/j8y18lte:8.0.0/R16NW/J810GDDU2ARK4:user/release-keys'
>   12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505): Revision: '4' 12-20 14:16:17.717
>   F/DEBUG   ( 9505): ABI: 'arm' 12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505):
>   pid: 8882, tid: 8882, name: um.m2smart.navi  >>>
>   jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi <<< 12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505):
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 12-20
>   14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505): Cause: null pointer dereference 12-20
>   14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505):     r0 00000000  r1 00004001  r2
>   00000000  r3 00000001 12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505):     r4
>   ca9f7800  r5 d056268c  r6 05f5ecb9  r7 ca9f7814 12-20 14:16:17.717
>   F/DEBUG   ( 9505):     r8 ffd3d5cc  r9 00000000  sl ca9f7820  fp
>   ffd3d5b4 12-20 14:16:17.717 F/DEBUG   ( 9505):     ip cee1355c  sp
>   ffd3d5b0  lr ce06bdec  pc ce2680e4  cpsr 80010010 12-20 14:16:17.718
>   F/DEBUG   ( 9505):  12-20 14:16:17.718 F/DEBUG   ( 9505): backtrace:
>   12-20 14:16:17.718 F/DEBUG   ( 9505):     #00 pc 0049b0e4 
>   /data/app/jp.co.zero_sum.m2smart.navi-wN3IIxzrjOdkZlYLW_XUDQ==/lib/arm/libMAPSJNI.so

Comment: stacktrace and minidump can be downloaded the following link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dN4FQi-khxi9Hp__tUOFEjwfDn8XDO5p

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for bringing this issue to our attention. We will provide a solution within the SDK release 3.11.